# Custom ArrayAdapter in ListFragment error

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I get an error when I try to run the code for my app after trying to add a list view using a custom `ArrayAdapter` in a class derived from `ListFragment`.

**Logcat:**

```
09-12 02:21:27.818  31354-31354/com.example.anas.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.anas.myapplication, PID: 31354
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.anas.myapplication.adapter.MaalomaListAdapter.getView(MaalomaListAdapter.java:74)
```

The error is produced in the following line the method getView():

```
viewHolder.ivMaaloma.setImageResource(R.drawable.maaloma_bg_1); 
viewHolder.tvMaaloma.setText(maaloma.getText());
```

To get a clearer idea of what I'm trying to do, this is my custom `ArrayAdapter` class (I marked error line with a comment):

**MaalomaListAdapter.java:**

```
public class MaalomaListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Maaloma> {

    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    private List<Maaloma> maalomaList;

    public MaalomaListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Maaloma> maalomaList) {
        super(context, resource, maalomaList);

        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.maalomaList = maalomaList;
    }

    public static int getResId(String resName, Class<?> c) {

        try {
            Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resName);
            return idField.getInt(idField);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // inflate item layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) this.context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(this.resource, parent, false);

            // init view holder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivMaaloma = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_maaloma_bg);
            viewHolder.tvMaaloma = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_maaloma);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // recycling already inflated views
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Maaloma maaloma = maalomaList.get(position);

        //int imageResId = getResId(maaloma.getImage(), Drawable.class);

        /**** ERROR COMES FROM THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES (WHICHEVER WAS FIRST) *****/
        viewHolder.ivMaaloma.setImageResource(R.drawable.maaloma_bg_1); 
        viewHolder.tvMaaloma.setText(maaloma.getText());

        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView ivMaaloma;
        private TextView tvMaaloma;

    }
}
```

I suppose the error resides in this class only but I'm ready to post more code upon request. Appreciate the time and effort guys.

Comment: check the id's of views in layout file... i think they are not exist there..

Comment: @skywall it's this one `viewHolder.ivMaaloma.setImageResource(R.drawable.maaloma_bg_1)`. I marked it with an all caps `/* */` comment in the class code. (Out of topic: If there's a trick I can use on SO for that you could let me know please)

Comment: They're there @sourabhbans, I used the wrong XML file in my ListFragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the layout you using during error?

It is likely that the layout you used do not have 
`R.id.iv_maaloma_bg` or `R.id.tv_maaloma`

Comment: They're there, I just used the wrong XML file as a resource in my ListFragment.